# Maven runs JUnit tests in Eclipse but compilation fails from the command line

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, junit

I have created a very simple project in Eclipse to run a very simple JUnit test. These tests work fine when tests are executed from within Eclipse, but the code does not compile when run via maven command line.

The command I am using to run maven is simply 'maven test'.  The following is the maven output:

```
MacBook-Pro:leonard-reference-test randy$ mvn test
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] Using the builder org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder with a thread count of 1
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building leonard-reference-test 0.0.1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ leonard-reference-test ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile (default-compile) @ leonard-reference-test ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to /Users/randy/PSH/workspaces/playground/leonard-reference-test/target/classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /Users/randy/PSH/workspaces/playground/leonard-reference-test/src/main/java/info/leonard/reference/test/ReferenceTestClient.java:[3,17] package org.junit does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/randy/PSH/workspaces/playground/leonard-reference-test/src/main/java/info/leonard/reference/test/ReferenceTestClient.java:[8,10] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Test
  location: class info.leonard.reference.test.ReferenceTestClient
[INFO] 2 errors
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.043 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-12-15T19:10:49-07:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/245M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile (default-compile) on project leonard-reference-test: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /Users/randy/PSH/workspaces/playground/leonard-reference-test/src/main/java/info/leonard/reference/test/ReferenceTestClient.java:[3,17] package org.junit does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/randy/PSH/workspaces/playground/leonard-reference-test/src/main/java/info/leonard/reference/test/ReferenceTestClient.java:[8,10] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Test
[ERROR] location: class info.leonard.reference.test.ReferenceTestClient
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
MacBook-Pro:leonard-reference-test randy$
```

The pom.xml for this is as follows:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>info.leonard.reference</groupId>
    <artifactId>leonard-reference-test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>

    <prerequisites>
        <maven>3.0</maven>
    </prerequisites>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

And the only Java file in the project is as follows:

```
package info.leonard.reference.test;

import org.junit.Test;

public class ReferenceTestClient
{
    @Test
    public void testOne()
    {
        System.out.println("simple test");
    }
}
```

That's it... no other files in the project.  Maven tests run successfully from within Eclipse, but the code doesn't even compile from within Maven.

A valid pom.xml file, or other modifications to this simple project, is appreciated.

Comment: Check dependency in pom.xml whether got junit dependency or not. It is common mistake eclipse added junit to classpath even it doesn't exist in pom.xml. Eclipse might ask you before.

Comment: Yes, the pom.xml (listed above) does include junit version 4.12.

Comment: I think that it can be relative to the location of the test file. Do you have it under src/test/java?

Comment: Can check download junit jar in .m2 folder? Is it the jar contain required classes? Do simple javac to compile your test case with junit jar. Sometime might have broken jar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have your file in `src/main/java/` directory but the scope for the JUnit dependency is test. This means maven will not take it into account when compiling non-test code. Please put your file in `src/test/java`.

Comment: I think you mean src/test/java

Answer (score 1):

Test scope means that junit is only available in src/test/java

move

/Users/randy/PSH/workspaces/playground/leonard-reference-test/src/main/java/info/leonard/reference/test/ReferenceTestClient.java:

over to

/Users/randy/PSH/workspaces/playground/leonard-reference-test/src/test/java/info/leonard/reference/test/ReferenceTestClient.java: